# What token issuer I can use in Windows Azure?

Tags: azure, wif, claims-based-identity

I am building a multi-tenant application in Azure and planning to use Claims (WIF). I do not have ADFS hosted for issuing tokens to the users of my applications.

What options do I have? Is there any commercial offering available?

Thanks & Regards,

Ajay

Answer (score 1):

Azure provides it own token issure  in [AppFabric Access Control](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/appfabric/) . Check Michele L. Bustamante 's [Access Control in the Cloud: Windows Azure AppFabric's ACS](http://www.devproconnections.com/article/net-framework2/Access-Control-in-the-Cloud-Windows-Azure-AppFabric-s-ACS.aspx) for a very well written intro. There's also a [demo video at Channel9](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/JackGr/Fabrikam-Jets-Integrating-Codename-Dallas-with-AppFabric-Access-Control/) on using AC and a client's ADFS to control access to an Azure service, in this case Dallas.

Answer (score 1):

You can now try ACS labs (early version of the service): http://acs.codeplex.com

It now supports WS-Federation.

my old post-->

AppFabric Access Control can currently only be used for REST endpoints (WRAP, SWT). If you Windows Azure app is a web site, you probably need an STS that supports WS-Federation.

You can build your own (and deploy it on Windows Azure) or you can rely on an STS hosted somewhere else.

To build your own I suggest looking athe [starter sts](http://startersts.codeplex.com/)